# How to put two images in a navbar next to each other when mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I need to put two png-s in navbar, and I need them to be next to each other when inside hamburger menu on smaller screens. Any sugestions? 
Here is my code so far:

```
<li class="nav-item" >
    <a id="insta" href="#" class="nav-link"><img width="35" height="35" src="insta.png" alt=""></a>
        </li>
    <li class="nav-item" >
      <a id="insta" href="#" class="nav-link"><img width="35" height="35" src="insta.png" alt=""></a>    
      </li>
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 4
Use this media query for mobile

```
@media (max-width: 576px) { 
.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
  }

}
```

If you are using Bootstrap 3
Use this media query for mobile

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { 
.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an inline-block, like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  li.nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
  }

}
```